# Database design to handle multiple addresses of hotels

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a website where hotels can register themselves. I use a unique email id for every hotel. Recently there have been cases where people have multiple branches of the same hotel. Now I cant expect them to have multiple email-ids.I know I can store the addresses of branches in a separate table, but what is the best approach if anyone has a similar scenario?

Comment: If a hotel can have multiple addresses, create a many-to-one relationship between the address table and the hotel table.  (Address has a foreign key to the Hotel to which it belongs.)  The same is true of emails, or any contact information.  Your last sentence implies that you know this, so it's not clear what you're asking...

Comment: Yes i know that is the obvious solution,but its not just the about multiple addresses, in the long term they could have different rates and many more. Is there a more robust way of handling multiple profiles with same login? what design do such websites usually implement?

Comment: Kind of too broad to answer here, but think about what the actual entities are.  It sounds like you are talking about a hotel company entity and a hotel property entity. Multiple properties can relate to a single company.  The properties themselves probably have one-to-many relationships to room types, rate cards, etc.

Comment: @rohitnaidu19: The patterns for modeling the data are still the same, separate distinct entities and create key relationships between them.  In the long term they could want all sorts of changes, but you can't design a generic system to meet every possible future need.  There has to be some defined set of axes on which data can vary.  If there's a change years from now to vary on something new, then that's simply a change to requirements and new development work would be needed to accommodate it.

Comment: Do you recommend giving a completely different profile for every branch? Would it be better if i linked one email id to multiple branches treating branches as distinct entities.